# Vue.js API call to existing API with JSON response - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have an API set on a device in my home which I access with port forwarding.

When I open `<my_ip>/api/example` from mine or other network I can see the JSON response in the browser.

When I make an axios vue.js get request to `<my_ip>/api/example` it returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

If I run the same thing with `<local_ip>/api/example` on my own PC - it works fine.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: what are you using to deploy that api?

Comment: It's the Philips Hue API up and running on my Philips Hue bridge. It's fully functional locally and remotely, but once I call it from axios it returns err_conection_refused.